# Does adding a force on top of stressed cable, in its free portion, adds to the initial stress

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A cable is stressed between two points, A on its first end, and B near its second end, by a force of 100KN, and a free portion near B remains without stress.

Please refer to attached image:
[image: Cable stressed before adding another force]

Now B holds this 100KN by simply holding a lock attached on its cable. So if the cable is moved even by 1mm, this support vanishes.

Then the free end C is pushed with a force of 20KN. Now does force moves the cable away from its support at B, so the 100KN disappears? or does it adds to the 100KN to become a 120KN stress?

Comment: in Eng-Forum an answer said: AB load remains 100kN; BC load is 20kN. Reaction at B is 80kN on the slab and 20kN by the pull force from C. My Engineering boss used to say the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible explanation of why the stress (and tension) between A and B would not change.

For the tension in AB to decrease, the AB section of the cable would have to shrink, which is not possible due to the rigid structure that keeps it stretched.

For the tension in AB to increase, the AB section has stretch more than it is already stretched, which can happen only if the top end of the AB section of the cable, held by B, moves up, but, for that to happen, B has to move up, which would be possible only if the force pulling it up exceeds $100$KN, which it does not (it is only $20$KN). So, B will stay put and therefore the top end of the AB section of the cable won't move up and, therefore, the AB section of the cable would not stretch any more and its tension (and stress) won't increase.